# Translating Python2 to Python3: "Cannot import name 'wmldata'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

The project has, briefly, the following structure:

```
/wmlvalidator.py
/wesnoth/__init__.py
/wesnoth/wmlgrammar.py
/wesnoth/wmlparser.py
/wesnoth/wmldata.py
```

In `/wmlvalidator.py` script, I have:

```
import wesnoth.wmldata as wmldata
import wesnoth.wmlparser as wmlparser
import wesnoth.wmlgrammar as wmlgrammar
```

The `/wesnoth/wmlgrammar.py` script only imports the Python standard library.

The script `/wesnoth/wmlparser.py` has:

```
import os, glob, sys
from . import wmldata
import re
```

The script `/wesnoth/wmldata.py` has:

```
import re, sys
from . import wmlparser
import codecs
```

The script `/wesnoth/__init__.py` is empty.

When I run `/wmlvalidator.py`, I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2357, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1777, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/wesnoth/data/tools/wmlvalidator", line 10, in <module>
    import wesnoth.wmldata as wmldata
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/wesnoth/data/tools/wesnoth/wmldata.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import wmlparser
  File "/home/macabeus/ApenasMeu/wesnoth/data/tools/wesnoth/wmlparser.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import wmldata
ImportError: cannot import name 'wmldata'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a circular dependency , that is never a good thing.

This circular dependency is what is causing the issue , Since first when you try to import `wmldata` from `.` , it finds the line `from . import wmlparser` and tries to import that module , while in the process of importing `.` and `wmldata` .

Then when it is trying to import `wmlparser` , it sees the line to import `wmldata` from `.` , but `.` has not been imported yet, hence it does not have a `wmldata` in it yet, and this causes the issue.

A way to fix this would be to change the `from . import wmldata` line in `wmlparser` to -

```
import wesnoth.wmldata as wmldata
```

And the import in your `wmldata` to -

```
import wesnoth.wmlparser as wmlparser
```

The best fix here would be to get rid of this circular dependency, as there may be other issues arising from this , that I cannot see since you did not include the complete code. Like , if `wmlparser` is using some name/variable defined in `wmldata` it would throw an error that that name has not been defined yet, since it has not been defined, when `wmldata` tried to import `wmlparser`.

Comment: I had tried to use this command, but still get error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wmldata'`. The project is open source and the complete code found here: https://github.com/wesnoth/wesnoth/tree/master/data/tools. 
Warning: it's a lot of thing =P

Comment: try changing both `from .` statements to `import` .

Comment: It did not solve the problem. The error message remains the same.

Comment: Even the line number from which the error is thrown ?

Comment: Yes, but I decided to remove the dependency. Studying the code, I realized that when `wmldata` is imported, the `wmlparser` is also. Soon, there will be problems if the files are merged. Thank you.